# Header files not recognized in PROC compiler 12.2 even with SYSHDRS in mkmf of HP-U

Tags: oracle, proc, embedded-sql

I am using the Pro*C 12.2 precompiler.

I have a `.c` file which is using `free()`, but `string.h` is not included in the `.c`, `.h` or `.pc` files.

The `Makefile` has `SYSHDRS= /usr/include` other files, but not `string.h`.

The executable after compilation is working in an Oracle 11g environment, but not in 12.2.

Note that `#include <string.h>` is not there in 11g and 12.2, also in the `.c` file. But it works for Oracle 11g and produces a memory fault for 12.2.

In the `Makefile` the only difference is the `ORACLE_HOME` path — in the former it is pointing to 11g and in the latter to 12.2.

Is there any difference between the 11g and 12.2 precompilers related to header files? For both environments `string.h` is present in `/usr/include`.

A solution I found was to include `string.h` in the `.pc` file. But this is only a temporary solution. Other `.pc` files are also missing `signal.h`, and the resulting executable produces a memory fault for 12.2.

Please guide me!

Comment: If building the executable works, the problem cannot be a missing header file.

Comment: I'm a little lost. You're talk about `free` but then you mention `string.h`. Unless something changed very recently `free` is defined in `stdlib.h`. ???

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me explain it clearly executable compiled with 12.2 does not work. It throws Memory fault. executable compiled with 11g works with no change in the setup or environment. Only changes is the ORACLE_HOME Path in the Makefile between 11g and 12.2. I agree free() is in stdlib.h but I was getting error in the line no of free() as per gdb back trace. free() was called  and defined as below in my code.free_mem();
void free_mem()
{
 free((void *)grp_struct);
 free((void *)grp_date);
}
void free_mem();

Comment: My Program was having #include<stdlib.h> already. May be it was missing String.h for some strcpy().